# C# - Help optimizing a loop

Tags: c#, .net

I have a piece of code that in principal looks like the below. The issue is that I am triggering this code 10's of thousands of times and need it to be more optimized. Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
//This array is in reality enormous and needs to be triggered loads of times in my code
int[] someArray = { 1, 631, 632, 800, 801, 1600, 1601, 2211, 2212, 2601, 2602 };

//I need to know where in the array a certain value is located
//806 is located between entry 801 and 1600 so I want the array ID of 801 to be returned (4).
id = 806

//Since my arrays are very large, this operation takes far too long 
for (int i = 0; i < someArrayLenght; i++)
{
  if (someArray[i] <= id)
    return i;
}
```

Edit: Sorry got the condition wrong. It should return the id when 806 is greater than 801. Hope you can make sense ot ouf it.

Comment: Are all the values in the array unique and ordered? And is the array modified between calls?

Comment: I think this question is more relevant to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what you called array ID (4) is simply the element index.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The array values look sorted. If that’s indeed the case, use [binary search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx):

```
int result = Array.BinarySearch(someArray, id);
return result < 0 ? (~result - 1) : result;
```

If the searched value does not appear in the array, `Array.BinarySearch` will return the bitwise complement of the next greater value’s index. This is why I am testing for negative numbers and using the bitwise complement operator in the code above. The result should then be the same as in your code.

Binary search has logarithmic running time instead of linear. That is, in the worst case only log<sub>2</sub> *n* many entries have to be searched instead of *n* (where *n* is the array’s size).

Comment: id (806) is not a part of the array. 801 is in the array and 1600 is in the array. I want 801 to be returned when 806 has been given.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo That’s no problem. The code works even then, just subtract 1 from the bitwise complement of `result`.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo: Look at the docs for `BinarySearch` and what it returns if the ID isn't found.

Answer (score 2):

Providing `someArray`'s content is sorted, use [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) — see also [`Array.BinarySearch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.binarysearch.aspx).

Note: In your example the condition in `if (someArray[i] <= id) return i;` will trigger whenever `id >= 1`. I doubt that's what you want to do.

Comment: id (806) is not a part of the array. 801 is in the array and 1600 is in the array. I want 801 to be returned when 806 has been given since it's between the two.

Comment: @BlueVoodoo Binary search is a trivial algorithm and you can implement it in a way that lets you select either the lower or upper match in case the input is not exactly present in the array. Please note that to use that algorithm the array **must** be sorted.

Comment: Thanks. The array is sorted at all times so that shouldn't be an issue.